# What does "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to 'Double' and 'Int'" Mean - What is Double?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't really understand what 'Double' means. I am trying to write basic code for `suvat - mechanics equations`.

```
let displacement = (initialVelocity*time) + (0.5*(acceleration*(time*time)))
```

The equation is `s = ut + 1/2at^2`

```
let initialVelocity = 3 
let acceleration = 2 
let time = 5 
let finalVelocity = initialVelocity + (acceleration * time) 
print ("The final Velocity is (finalVelocity)") 
let half = 0.5 
let accelerationTimeSquared = acceleration * (time * time) 
let displacement = (initialVelocitytime) + (0.5 * (acceleration * (time * time))) 
print("The displacement is (displacement)")
```

Comment: [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: please share the declaration of the variables and more context

Comment: let initialVelocity = 3

let acceleration = 2

let time = 5

let finalVelocity = initialVelocity + (acceleration*time)

print ("The final Velocity is \(finalVelocity)")

let half = 0.5


let accelerationTimeSquared = acceleration*(time*time)

let displacement = (initialVelocity*time) + (0.5*(acceleration*(time*time)))

print("The displacement is \(displacement)")

Comment: @EmemUmoh if you need a quick answer what you need is to add `Double` as explicit type for all your variables like `let initialVelocity:Double = 3` but maybe you should read : The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)

Answer (score 4):

"Double" stands for double-precision floating point number. This relates to how the number is stored in memory, its precision in decimal digits, and the range it can span. From [the Swift 2.2 language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> "Double represents a 64-bit floating-point number." and "Double has a
>   precision of at least 15 decimal digits"

For your specific issue, consider this code:

```
let initialVelocitytime = 6
let acceleration = 4.5
let time = 3.5
let displacement = Double(initialVelocitytime) + (0.5*(acceleration*(time*time)))

print(displacement)
```

In this example, I have mixed types `initialVelocitytime` (which is an Int) and the result of `(0.5*(acceleration*(time*time)))` (which evaluates to a Double). In order to use + to add them, I am casting the initialVelocityType to a Double value like so: `Double(initialVelocitytime)`. Whenever you want to mix an Int type (which does not have a decimal place, such as 14 or -212) with a Double type, you can cast the Int variable in this way. If one of your variables such as acceleration or time is an Int, you'll want to cast it that way too, i.e. `Double(acceleration)`, or in total:

```
let displacement = Double(initialVelocitytime) + (0.5*(Double(acceleration)*(time*time)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Doubles are floating point numbers and have more precision, such as decimal places. You generally have to convert an Int to be able to do operations with a Double. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528748/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-double)

Comment: So how would I do that in my case - let displacement = double

Comment: As such: let displacement = Double(initialVelocitytime) + (0.5 * Double(acceleration * (time * time)))