# Multiply a number in swift with more than 10 digits

Tags: swift, multiplication

I want to perform a multiplication like as shown below:

```
let a = 10
let b = a * (1e + 9)
```

how can I perform so??

and after multiplication, how can I show the result in this very format?

like `b = 1e + 10`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528748/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-double.

Comment: Please read the error message: It's pretty clear (by the way the scientific notation must be `1e+9` without spaces)

Comment: @MartinR this is not a possible duplicate.

Comment: You can show the result in scientific notation only as string: `print(String(format: "%g", b))`

Comment: You have to use NumberFormatter and convert it into decimal style and calculate @Madhur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the scientific notation to declare a numeric literal, its type is inferred to be `Double`, so you need to convert it to `Int` to be able to multiply an `Int` with your numeric literal (or the other way around if you actually expect a `Double` result).

Also make sure that there are no spaces in your scientific notation (you can also leave out the `+`).

```
let ten = 10
let multiplied = ten * Int(1e+9)
```

In case the scientific literal is actually a `Double`, convert the `Int` to a `Double`, not the other way around:

```
let one = Double(ten) * 1e-1
```